# Xcode: Setting Other C Flags on Aggregate Target

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries

I have an Aggregate Target for a static library that I'm building in Xcode 5.1.1. I'd like to set some **Other C Flags** on the target as I would if I were building against an Application target. However, "Other C Flags" isn't present in the target's Build Settings.

Application Target:
[image: application-target]

Aggregate Target:
[image: aggregate-target]

I need to do this to [rename symbols](http://atastypixel.com/blog/avoiding-duplicate-symbol-issues-when-using-common-utilities-within-a-static-library/) that I'm building into the static library. How can I achieve this, or is there another way to use the preprocessor?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the correct way to do this. My aggregate targets build from the application target in a run script defined in my build phases. By setting my Other C Flags in the application target, the Aggregate target correctly inherited those flags. So: just set the flags in the application target that the aggregate target references.